# How to Google search for big stories without a keyword restricting me?

Tags: google-search

I'm looking for any news between the dates of January 1, 2015 and January 17, 2015. How can I look for the popular stories without restricting my search with a keyword? I know how to search by date, but not how to bring up the most popular articles (as news.google.com automatically does) without using a keyword to search.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

assuming chrome being used:

url bar >   news:"DATE RANGE"+keyword

Comment: I Don't want to use a keyword, it's too restricting. I'm looking for all articles, covering a range of topics.

Comment: restricting how?   example might help

Comment: If I type a keyword in like 'World' it only includes articles with the word world included, but I need everything to be included, sorted by popularity. Even if the keyword 'a' were used, which every article is guaranteed to have, it would be completely random, or in alphabetical order. I don't want to have to comb through, in alphabetical order, every single article.

Comment: ok now i get it use this:   news:world&sort=ratings-stars:a  (the :a is to append the sort attribute to the search param)

Comment: this from https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#sort_by_attribute

Comment: When used, Does nothing. Page does a little mini refresh. Or it google searches it